# Extract InstallSHIELD's CAB files when there is no HDR files?

Tags: extract, hdr, installshield, cab

```
layout.bin
setup.lid
_sys1.cab
_user1.cab
DATA.TAG
data1.cab
SETUP.INI
setup.ins
_INST32I.EX_
SETUP.EXE
_ISDEL.EXE
_SETUP.DLL
lang.dat
os.dat
```

I want to extract an InstallSHIELD's 5 install package and above is the list of files in "data1" folder. However there is no *.hdr files so I can't extact the CAB files using tools on Internet, even though the package is still able to be installed without any error. Can anybody give me a suggestion for this please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extract an InstallShield Cabinet file?](http://superuser.com/questions/88645/how-to-extract-an-installshield-cabinet-file)

Comment: I tried all the solution in the link you posted but none worked. And my question is about the case with missing file.

Answer (score 1):

For that, you need [I5Comp](http://www.google.com/search?safe=off&q=i5comp). If it doesn’t work, try I3Comp, then finally IComp.

Answer (score 1):

Try [UniExtract](http://legroom.net/software/uniextract). It lists Installshield .cab in its list od suppored formats.